# What is the acknowledge mode of sqs if I don't explicitly specify it when I used SqsListener annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I am using SqsListener annotation in my code to listen to the AWS sqs.

```
    @SqsListener(value = "${my-queue}")
    public void listenToMyQueue(MyEvent event){
        ......
    }
```

Now I have following questions -

- if I didn't specify explicitly the acknowledge mode, what is the default one? Is it "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE mode where every received message is acknowledged automatically (and therefore deleted from the underlying Amazon SQS queue)"?
- Then, is deletePolicy = ON_SUCCEEDED a kind of acknowledge mode (because it seems to be the same as AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE above to me)? If no, will that be possible that it is contradict with the ack mode?
- Given the case I used SqsListener annotation, how should I specify explicitly the ack mode? An example would be great.

Thanks in advance.